# How set onclick with LinearLayout (android)

Tags: android

I have used the following tutorial "https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/ "to display data onto Android using ListView and LinearLayout. I want to go to another screen when I click on an item from the list. I have added this to my MainActivity but it didn't work:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       //ListView lv = getListView();

        buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
        buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        sendRequest();

        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EventDetails.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: A LinearLayout should not be a replacement for a ListView. Other than that, your code looks fine.

Comment: You code will start MainActivity again, is this what you want?

Comment: @m0skit0 it would start `EventDetails`

Comment: it will start Event Details

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set the LinearLayout to clickable.  You can either do this in the XML with adding below in linearlayout tag

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Or in code with

```
linearLayout.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial uses a ListView, not a LinearLayout.

You add Item-ClickListeners to ListViews.

```
final Context ctx = YourActivity.this;
yourListView = (ListView) findViewById...

yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Data clicked = adapter.getItem(position);

        // Do something with 'clicked'

        // startActivity(ctx, ShowDataActivity.class);
    }
});

int example_layout = android.R.simple_list_item_1;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Data>(ctx, example_layout, new ArrayList<Data>());
yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

By the way, [that tutorial uses a deprecated version of Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: what do u mean by depracated version, is there any other way you can show me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: "**deprecation** is the discouragement of use of some feature, design or practice" -- "no longer considered safe" -- In software, "no longer maintained or encouraged for general use".  You can still use Volley, but [**click the link**](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/README.md) and you'll see the word "deprecated" and it says what to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a public interface to manage the click events on the adapter elements. To do this, define a public interface in your adapter (in the tutorial is the CustomList class)

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


 public interface OnClickOnItemList
 {
    public void clickInView(View v,int position);
 }

 private OnClickOnItemList mListener;
 public setOnClickOnItemListener(OnClickOnItemList l) {this.mListener = l}
/*...*/

}
```

And in the same class go to getView. You should assign this new listener to the event onClick

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, null, true);

   linearLayout = (LinearLayout) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
   /*Rest of subviews*/


   /*Linear Layout now will call the new listener*/
   linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.clickInView(listViewItem,position);
        }
    });

    return listViewItem;
 }
}
```

Subsequently, the main activity must implement this public interface

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomList.OnClickOnItemList
{

 /*Code*/
 @Override
 public void clickInView(View v,int position)
 {
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EventDetails.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }

 private void showJSON(String json){
    ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    CustomList cl = new CustomList(this, ParseJSON.ids,ParseJSON.names,ParseJSON.emails);
    cl.setOnClickOnItemListener(this);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);
}

}
```

Comment: when I try to declare LinearLayout  linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout). I get an error in findViewById, how can i fix this

Comment: for this line of code  : public setOnClickOnItemListener(OnClickOnItemList l) {this.mListener = l;}. I get an error saying "There is no default constructor available in "android.widget.ArrayAdapter"".

Comment: However, for this line of code "LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); " I get the following error message "Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(Int)'". Could you suggest me what I can do ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My bad sorry :). You must specify the view, like this: linearLayout = (LinearLayout) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); and assign the listener. I edited the code

Comment: Thanks for that, However I still get an error for this line of code :   public setOnClickOnItemListener(OnClickOnItemList l) {this.mListener = l;}  It says "There is no default constructor available in "android.widget.ArrayAdapter""

Comment: I've added the code needed to implement the interface. You must implement the rest of the code you have in the tutorial. You should also consider what cricket says, Volley's version is in disarray and you should use an updated version

Comment: Hello, i havent had any luck, I still get an error in that same line, and also when I include the showJSON function in the MainActivity, I get an error for this "setOnClickOnItemListener" saying cannot resolve method. Is there any other way that you can help me please

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/yourid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
```